# How to find a solution to the linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

For the linear equations

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&R^lx_1+R^{-l}x_2&=\frac{1}{2\pi}f_l\\
&{r_n}^lx_1+{r_n}^{-l}x_2-{r_n}^lx_3-{r_n}^{-l}x_4&=0\\
&{r_n}^lx_1-{r_n}^{-l}x_2-k_n{r_n}^lx_3+k_n{r_n}^{-l}x_4&=0\\
&{r_{n-1}}^lx_3+{r_{n-1}}^{-l}x_4-{r_{n-1}}^lx_5-{r_{n-1}}^{-l}x_6&=0\\
&{r_{n-1}}^lx_3-{r_{n-1}}^{-l}x_4-k_{n-1}{r_{n-1}}^lx_5+k_{n-1}{r_{n-1}}^{-l}x_6&=0\\
\vdots\\
&(k_1-1){r_1}^{l}x_{2n-1}+(k_1+1){r_1}^{-l}x_{2n}&=0
\end{aligned}\right.$$

The linear equations are in my recent studies, I have in trouble with finding a solution.

Or

Is there any methods to calculate the determinant(2n order)

$$\left|\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
R^l&R^{-l}&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
{r_n}^l&{r_n}^{-l}&-{r_n}^{l}&-{r_n}^{-l}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\{r_n}^l&-{r_n}^{-l}&-k_n{r_n}^l&k_n{r_n}^{-l}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&{r_{n-1}}^l&{r_{n-1}}^{-l}&-{r_{n-1}}^l&-{r_{n-1}}^{-l}&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&{r_{n-1}}^l&-{r_{n-1}}^{-l}&-k_{n-1}{r_{n-1}}^l&k_{n-1}{r_{n-1}}^{-l}&\cdots&0&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots& {r_2}^l&{r_2}^{-l}&-{r_2}^{l}&-{r_2}^{-l}\\0&0&0&0&0&0& \cdots&{r_2}^l&-{r_2}^{-l}&-k_2{r_2}^l&k_2{r_2}^{-l}\\0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0&(k_1-1){r_1}^l&(k_1+1){r_1}^{-l}\end{array}\right|
$$
Thanks to your help!

Comment: Do you need analytical or numeric solution? In the latter case, Gaussian elimination is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Suggestion: let $S = R^l$, so that $S^{-1} = R^{-l}$. Similarly, let $s_n = r_n^l$. This gets rid of most of your exponents.

Comment: Another suggestion: since the last row of the matrix does not follow a pattern from the prior rows, write out the two rows before it, so that we can see how the "pattern part" ends. That'll also make it clear why this is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix; for some time, I thought it had only $2n-1$ rows because I didn't notice the oddity of the last line.